# Access web2py session from PHP

Tags: ubuntu, web2py

Is there any way to access web2py session from PHP? I was thinking of parsing web2py session files with PHP to get information if user is logged in in web2py or not. But maybe there is some easier solutino?

Where web2py stores its session files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, web2py sessions are stored in files, and the session files for a given application are in /web2py/applications/yourapp/sessions (alternatively, sessions can be stored in the database or encrypted in cookies). The session data are serialized via the Python [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module, so you will need a way to deserialize the Python pickle format in PHP. For that, you might find these options helpful:

- https://github.com/terryf/Phpickle
- https://github.com/zendframework/zend-serializer/blob/release-2.8.0/src/Adapter/PythonPickle.php.

Note, if the reason you want to check the session for login is because you want to delegate authentication of the PHP app to the web2py app, you might instead be able to take advantage of web2py's built-in [CAS functionality](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Central-Authentication-Service).

Comment: Thank you that helped alot. I think that it's enough information to do it. Accepting answer.